# Unity3D C# System.IO.File.Delete not working on IOS

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I am downloading and storing and loading files from / to the Application.persistentDataPath which works fine.
Now I would like to delete some files, which works fine in editor but doesn't seem to work on ios.

It says "File does not exist" but it loads the file successfully. How is it possible that it does not exist, maybe is deleting denied on ios?

this is for loading (which works)

```
string localName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, filename);

 var www = new WWW(thumbnailLink);
        yield return www;
        //Save file
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes (localName, www.bytes);
```

Some time later, I want to delete the file like this:

```
System.IO.File.Delete (localName);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You add  "`/private`" in front of the file's name before calling the delete function.

```
System.IO.File.Delete ("/private" +localName);
```

That code is not portable. Use `#if UNITY_IPHONE` to check if this is iOS then do the modification so that it will work on Android too.

```
#if UNITY_IPHONE
System.IO.File.Delete ("/private" +localName);
#else
System.IO.File.Delete(localName);
#endif
```

Comment: It's a huge tip.  I've always wondered: when I make the path I only use simply `string p = Application.persistentDataPath+"/"+"blah.txt";` I do not bother using System.IO.Path.Combine.  I get the feeling that, in that case, one does *not* need to then use the /private pre-path when deleting on iOS.  But i've not taken the time to check it out.

Comment: similarly, I wonder if it is OK to "always add" the /private (when on iOS) so that it is consistent when you build the path, for both writing and deleting.

Comment: @JoeBlow. You still need `Application.persistentDataPath`. `localName` is the variable from the question OP made. So it should look like something  `File.Delete("/private" + Application.persistentDataPath+"/"+filename);` For your question, No. This only applies to the `File.Delete` function  as far as I know and it is a bug in Unity. So only use it when using calling the `Delete` function.

Comment: no of course, what I'm saying is rather than using ***System.IO.Path.Combine*** I simply "+" add them....what I mean is at the step of creating the path.

Comment: ah you think it was just a bug ....... you know, I think they ***may have fixed it*** lately.  I can confirm I have apps (even in store) where I did NOT BOTHER adding the "/private", and it works perfectly, seemingly.

Comment: @JoeBlow Ok. The places you did not bother adding the "/private" that worked, did you use the `Delete` function or were you just `reading` and `writing` files ?

Comment: Right: I am talking only of using "Delete". So, I had p = Application.persistentDataPath + "/picture1.png"; type of thing.  *{So, FWIW, I simply added rather than using System.IO.Path.Combine.  Maybe irrelevant.}* When using Delete, I used ONLY Delete(p).  (NOT Delete("/private"+p); )  It does seem to work perfectly.  Indeed, these are cases where I relied logically on the files being there or not.  (So, if they are "not there" it makes a "button light up" or whatever.) Indeed, I triple-checked and it is working perfectly actually in app store (recent version, last few weeks) on ios apps.

Comment: @JoeBlow It is likely that Unity has fixed this bug or iOS update fixed it. I can't remember what Unity version I had this problem with either. If it works now, then it is fixed and thanks for notifying me about that. The OP did not mention his Unity version and his iOS version.

Comment: right.  on the face of it, the problem does seem to be fixed.  an interesting question is, *does it still work* if one *does* prepend the /private prepath.  I don't know.  bizarrely, I have no knowledge of this and have never heard of the issue when doing ios native.  i just googled and indeed various folks talk about it (in a purely native context).  anyway .. time for more coffee  :/

Comment: @JoeBlow. Not sure. This was about a year ago I encountered this. To test it again I have to logout  out of Windows and login to my Mac. And at this moment I am running simulation that requires my computer to be on for 3 months 24/7. Lol You can test it and see if it works. I want  to know if it still work too.